# How to always call a function from a JavaScript object literal, not only when the object is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I hope my title isn't too confusing. An example first. I have the following code that configures the read operation for a [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/introduction.aspx) data source. I am trying to filter all reads based on the selected company id, but my `getSelectedCompanyId` function is only ever called once, when the page loads. The code below is too long to include all here, so just an excerpt.

```
$(function () {
    function getSelectedCompanyId() {
        var id = $("#CompanyId").val();
        return id;
    }

    $("#CompanyId").kendoDropDownList({
        change: function () {
            grid.dataSource.read();
        }
    });
    var departmentIndexDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("ListForCompanyIdJson", "Department")' + '?companyId=' + getSelectedCompanyId(),
                type: "GET"
            },
```

The `ListForCompanyIdJson` action is always called with the value selected in the dropdown when `$("#CompanyId").kendoDropDownList()` is called. I want this function to be called whenever I call `grid.dataSource.read()`.

I realize this might be highly specific to the Kendo stuff, but maybe it's something I can solve with plain JavaScript closures and some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install a replacement function for `grid.dataSource.read()` that always calls your function first and then calls `grid.dataSource.read()`.

For example:

```
grid.dataSource.oldRead = grid.dataSource.read;
grid.dataSource.read = function() {
    // call your function here
    return grid.datasource.oldRead.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Or, if you want to be able to call one sometimes and one other times, you can just make a new method that provides the new behavior and use it when you want to:

```
grid.dataSource.myread = function() {
    // call your function here
    return grid.datasource.read.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, your first solution looks almost helpful, but I want my function to be called by `grid.dataSource.read()`, when it builds the url. If I call my function then `grid.dataSource.oldRead`, I still don't know how to make my function influence `grid.dataSource.oldRead`.

I.e. I want the built-in `read` to use a url supplied my me (via my function), not the only url my function supplies the once `$("#CompanyId").kendoDropDownList` is called.

Comment: @ProfK - I don't know what URL you are talking about?  In your sample code, there is no URL argument to `grid.datasource.read()`.  What URL are you talking about?  If you want to set the URL on the datasource before doing the `read()`, you can do that as long as the datasource has methods for that.  Just call those methods before you call the `read()`.  If you're looking for help with something else, you will need to explain more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Look at the 'constructor' for the data source. It assigns a url to `transport.read.url`. It gets this url from my function. I want to assign a 'reference' to the url, not a fixed value, if that makes any more sense.

Comment: @ProfK - I see the constructor for `kendo.data.DataSource()`, but once that data has been passed into the constructor, we have no idea what it does with that data.  If, after constructing the object, you want to change the datasource URL, you will have to either call a method that supports changing the datasource, throw away the current object and create a new one with a new datasource URL or look at how the code works and figure out how you would create a method to change the datasource URL.

Comment: @ProfK - Javascript does not have pure string references that just always point to the latest edit you've made to an external variable (like you would have in a language like C++).  Strings in Javascript are actually immutable.   A string isn't actually changed.  When you carry out an operation on a string, it returns a new string with the modifications in it.  The old string is still what it was.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I guess there's more work ahead. I was hoping I could maybe pass a function to the `url` property instead of a string, along those lines. I think recreating the data source is easiest.